# Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit

Tags: solana, candy-machine

I type the command :

```bash
npx ts-node candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet \
 -k DEVw4sdjjwo3he1JgJbycZuWmZuC28YFMEY9uYpnP7cP.json -c cm2test \
 -cp /users/macbook/git/cmv2/setup/cmsetup.json \ 
 /users/macbook/git/cmv2/setup/uploadfolder
```

this gives me :

```
Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit
```

[cmsetup.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wEc2.png)

the solana balance gives me :

**0 SOL**

while if I type :

`solana airdrop 1 <RECIPIENT_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> --url https://api.devnet.solana.com`

and this :

`solana balance <ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> --url https://api.devnet.solana.com`

this gives me :

**2 SOL**

I'm stuck at this stage of the tutorial: https://youtu.be/wBWmO5zPpug?t=910

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but it looks like you're trying to use the keypair for the address `DEVw4sdjjwo3he1JgJbycZuWmZuC28YFMEY9uYpnP7cP` to do the deployment on devnet, but that account has no funds on devnet: https://explorer.solana.com/address/DEVw4sdjjwo3he1JgJbycZuWmZuC28YFMEY9uYpnP7cP?cluster=devnet

I'm not sure exactly how the script works, but to be safe, you can airdrop into both your default account and that account:

```
solana --url devnet airdrop 1
solana --url devnet airdrop 1 DEVw4sdjjwo3he1JgJbycZuWmZuC28YFMEY9uYpnP7cP
```

Comment: I wasn't using the command line, but had the same issue - I had done an airdrop to my local validator, but was accidentally trying to mint something on mainnet.